# Проблема с сохранением и отправкой куки

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookie, fetch

Занимаюсь разработкой фронтенд-части веб-приложения. В процессе работы над реализацией авторизации столкнулся с некоторыми трудностями. На странице "логин" успешно получаю ключ, который изначально сохраняется в куки. Однако, после перезагрузки страницы этот куки исчезает, что мешает успешной передаче ключа. Подозреваю, что это связано с тем, что сервер не находится локально, а веб-страница, над которой я работаю, развернута на localhost.

При ручном сохранении токена он остается, но при отправке GET-запроса для получения данных о пользователе куки также не отправляются.

Попытка поставить заголовок вручную так же не приносит никакого результата

```
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Cookie': 'name=ivan'
    }
  })
```

В то же время, при использовании Postman все функционирует корректно.
Как заставить chrome отправить все таки куки?

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Однако, после перезагрузки страницы этот куки исчезает — разбирайтесь с этим. Браузер не даст отправить куку вручную в fetch https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header

Comment: Это решаемая проблема. Основной вопрос как отправить куки с localhost на сервер.

Comment: Эти куки должен был поставить сервер